# Issue does not show when training full

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm creating an application where an user can book a training. I made that when the training has reached max slots no one can book anymore. I'm trying to show an error when this happens, but the error doesn't appear, the method works, it does not let anyone join in the training but the application needs to tell the user that he cant book because the training is full.

I would like some help to know why the error is not showing and how can i fix it

Booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true
  validate :training_not_full?, on: :create



private

  def training_not_full?
    errors.add(:training, "Full training. Try another hour") unless training.can_book?
  end

end
```

Training model:

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings

  def can_book?
    bookings.count < slots
  end

end
```

Show training view:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.left_slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>

    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
    </center>
```

Booking form view:

```
<%= form_for(@training) do |f| %>

<% if f.object.errors.any? %>
  <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |full_message| %>
    <p>
      <%= full_message %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>    
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
          <% if current_user.not_booked?(@training) %>
          <%= link_to "Book", new_training_booking_path(@training), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% else %>
            <% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
        <%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(booking.training, booking), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you certain you want to delete this?' }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

New booking view:

```
<h1>Book confirmation</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for ([@training, @booking]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :training_id, value: "" %>
      <%= f.submit "Confirm booking", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the implementation of the add method is changed in Rails 5.

Please try

```
def training_not_full?
  errors.add(:training, :full, message: "Full training. Try another hour") unless training.can_book?
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

instead of

```
def training_not_full?
  errors.add(:training, "Full training. Try another hour") unless training.can_book?
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

Please change your new.html.erb form:

```
<%= form_for ([@training, @booking]) do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
    <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |full_message| %>
      <p>
        <%= full_message %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :training_id, value: "" %>
  <%= f.submit "Confirmar reservacion", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it shows me this error now: undefined method `except' for "Full training. Try another hour":String Did you mean? exec. Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sCV7T3akprwsTvH1FO/X8powg7xFzO9yS/D7plgsNcseZQFocmXtRMF5KXxQfQegykjDum1qrDOjWdm7ZkNRUQ==",
 "booking"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "training_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Confirmar reservacion",
 "training_id"=>"1"}

Comment: Please see my revised answer, i had to add "message: "

Comment: now it does not gives me any errors, but still not showing the message (same as before). theres no another method like flash that allows me show a message?

Comment: Can you share your view files?

Comment: You could always use the rails scaffold as a reference.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

Comment: It still not working :-( I updated the form with your update to see if i misstyped something

Comment: I see you use the new view when you have errors in you booking (https://github.com/cbrzn/boxApp/blob/master/app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb#L10).

Comment: You have to show the errors in the form you are showing (https://github.com/cbrzn/boxApp/blob/master/app/views/bookings/new.html.erb#L6).

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: it worked now! but it shows Training Full training. Try another hour. I dont know why the first "Training" word is there

Comment: The error is added to the training object with errors.add. Then you specify again the training variable with `errors.add --> :training`

Comment: You can do `errors.add(:base, :full, message: "Full training. Try another hour") unless training.can_book?` then it adds the error to the base of the training.

Comment: See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add